# slow query greater than or equal 7 sec from mysql log

Tags: sed

I want sloq query which have 7 or greater than 7 sec in mysql log.
mysql log file have size greater than 500 Mb so 
My script first select  the datewise slow query from mysql log and from that I am selecting query which is greater than 7 sec.  log output is below.

```
# Time: 161223 12:40:42
# User@Host: root[root] @  [10.160.15.69]
# Query_time: 5.307732  Lock_time: 0.000061 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined:30334028
```

use Dbname;
SET timestamp=1482477042;
SELECT PRR.pr_register_request_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE( '2015-12-23', '%Y-%m-%d' ) AND STR_TO_DATE( '2016-12-23', '%Y-%m-%d' )  EXISTS (SELECT item_master_id FROM item WHERE IM.item_master_item_code = PRR.pr_register_material_code );

Answer (score 0):

why not to use AWK ? $3 = third place in your line (time)

sample data (test.txt)

```
# Query_time: 9.353543 Lock_time: 0.000036 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 9091792 use Aarti_Engineering_Purchase; SET timestamp=1482477646; SELECT fieldvalue,I.InquiryID FROM FormMaster FM,FormDetail FD,Inquiry I,InquiryDetails I.InquiryID = ID.InquiryID AND AttributeValue IN ('ProjectCode');
# Query_time: 7.353543 Lock_time: 0.000036 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 9091792 use Aarti_Engineering_Purchase; SET timestamp=1482477646; SELECT fieldvalue,I.InquiryID FROM FormMaster FM,FormDetail FD,Inquiry I,InquiryDetails I.InquiryID = ID.InquiryID AND AttributeValue IN ('ProjectCode');
# Query_time: 9.353543 Lock_time: 0.000036 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 9091792 use Aarti_Engineering_Purchase; SET timestamp=1482477646; SELECT fieldvalue,I.InquiryID FROM FormMaster FM,FormDetail FD,Inquiry I,InquiryDetails I.InquiryID = ID.InquiryID AND AttributeValue IN ('ProjectCode');
# Query_time: 2.353543 Lock_time: 0.000036 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 9091792 use Aarti_Engineering_Purchase; SET timestamp=1482477646; SELECT fieldvalue,I.InquiryID FROM FormMaster FM,FormDetail FD,Inquiry I,InquiryDetails I.InquiryID = ID.InquiryID AND AttributeValue IN ('ProjectCode');
# Query_time: 28.353543 Lock_time: 0.000036 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 9091792 use Aarti_Engineering_Purchase; SET timestamp=1482477646; SELECT fieldvalue,I.InquiryID FROM FormMaster FM,FormDetail FD,Inquiry I,InquiryDetails I.InquiryID = ID.InquiryID AND AttributeValue IN ('ProjectCode');
```

and simply:

```
awk '$3 < 7' ./test.txt
```

or replace 7 with whatever time you want ... and store them in file

```
awk '$3 > 7.5' ./test.txt >> ./long_query.txt
```

Comment: In query other parameters also there like ...   # Time: 161223 12:50:46
# User@Host: root[root] @  [10.160.15.69]   at  that this awk not work properly

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep`:

```
grep 'Query_time: [7-9]' file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/Query_time: [7-9]/p' file
```

Comment: very odd things happening with me.  I have big file from it I am tailing like   tail -500 file > file1  and tail -2000 file > file2    your query is work if I have the file which have the 500 lines  here filew but if I have 2000 lines with file2  then  3,4,5 second query time also shows in output !!!  very very strange and odd for me to understand this.

Comment: @nirajvara, Pls update/edit your question with how your input file is exactly look like.

Comment: I have update my question no attachment option otherwise attach file also but its a normal mysql log only.